# Разделить массив на два массива по n элементов js

Tags: javascript

Имеется массив объектов:

```
array = [{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, ... {n}]
```

Как разделить этот массив на два массива, по 4 объекта? В первый массив 4 элемента, во второй массив 4 элемента, потом снова в первый, во второй, до конца массива. Чтобы было так:

```
array1 = [{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {9}, ...] и array2 = [{5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {13}, ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = [];
let array1 = [];
let array2 = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
  array.push({
    val: i
  })
}

while (array.length) {
  array1.push(array.splice(0, 4));
  array2.push(array.splice(0, 4));
}

array1 = array1.flat();
array2 = array2.flat();

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```